# Giving my Python application a web interface to monitor it, using Tornado

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon, tornado

I've got a Python application which is daemonized and running on a server 24/7. I'd like to be able to give an incredibly simple web interface so that I can monitor the changing values of a few variables within the program.

I'm using Tornado, and I'm up and running with the simple 'Hello, world' that you can find on the [Tornado homepage](http://www.tornadoweb.org/). However, as soon as `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()` is called, it enters into the loop and doesn't return. My existing program is (essentially) an infinite loop as well, but I want to integrate the two.

So, my question is: how can I construct my program so that I can monitor variables inside my infinite loop by using Tornado to provide a web interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible to use the `threading` package and run Tornado inside of its own thread?

**Edit:**

The `threading` module documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html has more details, but I am imagining something like this:

```
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start)
t.start()
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: This sounds like the kind of route I'd rather go down - how can I run Tornado inside of its own thread using `threading`?

Comment: I have tried adding some code; take a look and see if it gets you started!

Comment: And if you set `t.daemon = True` on the thread before starting it, then the thread — and Tornado with it — will shut down when the main thread that is running your daemon exits.

Comment: Even if he gets Tornado running in a thread, he's still got to find a way to communicate between the two. Which means using a database/file of some sort (as Charles' solution suggests anyway) or hacking Tornado and using pipes -- seems like a big mess to me. Running the webserver separate seems like a much more solid solution. If it crashes it won't take the OPs app down with it. It sounds to me he just needs the web interface as an optional way to control his app's behavior, so there's no need for the two to be always running at the same time.

Comment: Why won't his Tornado classes just import his application classes and introspect their state? Remember that Python threads are share a single interpreter state.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the best (read: easiest) approach would be to have your daemon app write those particular variables you want to monitor out to a shared spaced that your tornado app can access. This could be a file, a socket, a database, or key-value store. Some ideas ideas that come to mind is to use your existing database (if there is one,) sqlite, or even memcached. Then, you would simply have your tornado application read those values from wherever you stored them.

You are correct in that once you run `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()` tornado's control flow never returns from that loop. From that point forward, your application's control will stay within the Application and RequestHandlers that you defined.

Comment: You are not very explicit about it, but am I correct that your suggestion is that he should run two processes instead of one, with one process running his daemon code and the other running the tornado event loop? If so, I am not sure that is a really great solution; coordinating two processes so that they always start and stop together can be a bit of a chore.

Answer (score 0):

Another less elegant solution would be to utilize yaml to serialize the objects periodically from your main app, and have the web app read those in.  You can even dump objects into yaml, so you could see the different states of those.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using http://www.zeromq.org/ to as a means of communication between to the two processes / threads.